# Java Swing: JTextArea filling entire allocated space

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.awt.*;

import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

public class mwe extends JFrame {

    private JPanel x, y, z, u,v,w,jtext;

    private class MyBorderedPanel extends JPanel {
        MyBorderedPanel( String title ) {
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED), title
            ));
        }
    }

    private class MyTextPanel extends JPanel {
        JTextArea textArea;
        MyTextPanel( String title ) {
            textArea= new JTextArea();
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),
                            title));
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane();
            pane.add(textArea);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            this.add(pane);
        }
    }

    public mwe() {
        x= new MyBorderedPanel("x");
        y= new MyBorderedPanel("y");
        z= new MyBorderedPanel("z");
        u= new MyBorderedPanel("u");
        v= new MyBorderedPanel("v");
        w= new MyBorderedPanel("w");
        jtext= new MyTextPanel("textArea");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        manageLayout();
    }

    private void manageLayout() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = BOTH;

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 13.00;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 4;
        this.add(x, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 8.00;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(y, constraints);


        { //adding dummes: 2x2, 1x1, 1x1
            constraints.gridx = 1;
            constraints.gridy = 1;
            constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 2.00;
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            constraints.gridheight = 2;
            this.add(u, constraints);

            constraints.gridx = 2;
            constraints.gridy = 1;
            constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 1.00;
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            constraints.gridheight = 1;
            this.add(v, constraints);

            constraints.gridx = 2;
            constraints.gridy = 2;
            constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 1.00;
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            constraints.gridheight = 1;
            this.add(v, constraints);
        }

        constraints.gridx = 3;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 5.00;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 3;
        this.add(jtext, constraints);


        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 3.00;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(z, constraints);
    }
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame= null;
                frame = new mwe();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have the above code that simulates the idea of Golden Ratio applied to GridBagLayout(). The output is as follows:
[image]
Now, as you can see the TextArea is empty. 
I would like its hosting panel be essentially filled with
"white" space, even if the text-area is empty at this point.
I remember having read here at SE that `BorderLayout` is the way to go,
so I tried it.
So, essentially, I would like the text-area to fill its hosting
panel to the brim, and also the scrollpane be visible.

How to achieve that? Probably the most relevant code of the above MWE is the MyTextPanel class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, as you can see the TextArea is empty.

This is because you haven't actually added the text area to the scroll pane.

```
JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane();
pane.add(textArea);
```

Above code is wrong. You don't "add" components directly to a JScrollPane.

Instead you add components to the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane`.

This is done by doing either:

```
JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

which will add the text area to the viewport, or

```
JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane();
pane.setViewportView(textArea);
```